# One week LIBOR?

Tags: interest-rate-swap, libor, bootstrapping

Are there any commonly traded instruments that would allow one to bootstrap a one week LIBOR curve?

If not, is there some alternate way to value forward starting swaps with a short first period that use interpolation between one week LIBOR and 1M LIBOR for the coupon of the first floating payment?

Comment: Do you mean 1w1w LIBOR? Since 1w LIBOR is a standard quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no traded instruments that would allow a 1w libor curve to be bootstrapped.  If you need to calculate a forward rate for 1week libor in the current environment, I would suggest that it can be bounded as follows :  overnight fed funds < 1 week libor < 1 month libor.   The forward rates on the bounds can be calculated from bootstrapped curves.